# Translating specific cUrl request into/with Java

Tags: java, apache, http, curl

I had an issue: I am trying to convert a curl request into java. Thusfar, I have tried the `makeCurl` `JAR` files as well as tried directly using Apache http. However, I can't figure out the conversion. I am new to both `Java` and `Curl`, so I know most of the issue is a lack of familiarity with the API. However, as this is time sensitive, I would really appreciate the help turning this relatively simple line of code into java.

```
curl \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer O3YPXEJHQ6TWNFI7HIBEGLVDBZA2SEKN' \
  'https://api.wit.ai/message?q=my_message'
```

Which returns:

```
{

  "msg_id" : "e0d5c96d-ca14-43a8-bcf9-993e5c717155",

  "msg_body" : "my_message",

  "outcome" : {
    "intent" : "greetings",
    "entities" : { },
    "confidence" : 0.525

  }
```

If I could get this return back into a string, I could finish the rest of the program. This one step has been a pain though. Thank you so much in advance for the help!

-Andrew

**Update:**

Okay: I can now send the request, and it is being received by the server, though I am using the entirely wrong code.  I tried the java.net.URL/URLConnection library, and used this:

```
package curlHttp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


public class curlStackTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String stringUrl = "https://api.wit.ai/message?q=test";
        URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();

        uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer O3YPXEJHQ6TWNFI7HIBEGLVDBZA2SEKN");


        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream());

        // read this input

    }
}
```

Now i just need to figure out how to read the output coming back from the cUrl request...

Answer (score 2):

Try with the following code

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStreamReader);

while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
}
```